# unable to append / concat the dataframes in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, append, concatenation

I have two data frames:

- `a` is with `(370,784)`
- `b` is with `(130,784)`

Both have same column names.

When I use `a.append(b,ignore_index=True)`, it shows below. I tried concat also but same results.

[image]

Comment: You should read the documentation of `concat`, you need to align or ignore the index

Comment: ignore_index ignores the index at the end not before

Comment: The columns are not the same. Maybe col names are in different types (int vs str).

Comment: column data types are same. int'64 for both dataframes.

Comment: I see I typed "or" in my comment, this should be "not" of course ;) The best woulf be for you to provide a minimal example of how you would like to concat/merge your datasets.

Comment: But i use append here and hence ignore_index. Dont know whats the issue